# How can I fix Webpack not recognizing oneOf type asset or asset/resource?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

After ejecting a React App built with `CRA`, I'm encountering issues with my `webpack.config.js`.

Errors are thrown for entries `[1]` and `[9]` of the `oneOf` rule produced by ejecting. For example:

```
configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].type should be one of these:
   "javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
```

Entries `[1]` and `[9]` have types set to `asset` and `asset/resource` respectively.

To me this seems like I might be missing a plugin. What should I do?